# Monomorphism and mapping of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, monomorphisms

Let $V$ and $W$ be two vector spaces, and let $f:V \rightarrow W$ be a linear mapping. Show that $f$ is a Monomorphism only when $f$ maps linearly independent sets in $V$ to linearly independent sets in $W$.

I sort of understand the idea as to why in the above case $f$ should be a Monomorphism. According to my Linear Algebra script, it describes a Monomorphism as an injective linear mapping. So, if my understanding is correct, if the vectors were not linearly independent in $W$ for example, then one vector in $V$ could map to several linearly dependent vectors in $W$ (which is not injective).

Is this an example of a proof where I just need to write out my reasoning, or is there a way to show that the above is true more "mathematically"?

Comment: How are you saying one vector in $V$ is going to several linearly dependent vectors? That is saying $f$ is not well defined. Not that it is not injective.

Comment: @AHusain So if linear dependence does not impact the mapping, how could we show that the function $f$ is injective when only dealing with linearly independent sets inside $V$ and $W$?

Comment: To show that such a mapping is *not* injective, you need to display two distinct elements in $V$ that map to the same element in $W$. Alternatively, show that if $f$ maps linearly independent vectors in $V$ to a linearly independent vectors in $W$, then the mapping is injective, i.e., under that assumption show that if $f(a) = f(b)$, then necessarily $a=b$. Use a basis for each space.

Comment: I would first concentrate on showing that $f$ mapping linearly independent sets in $V$ to linearly independent sets in $W$ is equivalent to $f$ being injective (which is also equivalent to $f$ having trivial kernel).  Then, you can show that $f$ being a monomorphism is equivalent to $f$ being injective (and for that, the usual hint for one direction is to consider the case where $g, h : F^1 \to V$).

Comment: Maybe the logical form of the proposition is confusing. It is equivalent to prove this: if $f : V \to W$ is an injective linear map and $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ are elements of $V$ such that $f (v_1), \ldots, f (v_n)$ are linearly dependent in $W$, then $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ are linearly dependent in $V$.